# Javascript object initialization, which is the best way to do it?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Object initialization:

```
var myObject = {};
```

and

```
var myObject = new Object();
```

why the last one is considered an antipattern?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure `new Object()` really falls under "anti-pattern", but `{}` is usually preferred, it's terse and more flexible at the same time.

When you're writing JavaScript you want it to end up short...if it can be terse and understandable when writing it as well, as this is:

```
var myObject = { key: "value" };
```

...then you get the best of both worlds.  Also when you're creating objects within objects, for example:

```
var myObject = { subObj: { key: "value" } };
```

...then you can see it's *much* more readable than the alternative `new Object()` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You always should prefer literals over constructors.

This is not really related to your question but here is an example with arrays. `new Array()` can be confusing at the first glance if you don't know how it works:

```
var a = [5,6];
var b = [5];
```

both create arrays with length 2 and 1 resp. But consider

```
var a = new Array(5,6);
var b = new Array(5);
```

The first one creates an array of length 2 ,containing the elements 5 and 6, 
the last one creates an **empty** array of **length** 5.

So you see, using literal notation avoids this pitfall.

Besides that, always using literal notation is consistent. When you create a string you also write `var t = "Hello world"` and not `var t = new String("Hello world")`.

Answer (score 1):

Well anti-pattern because of a problem with array constructors, it's just convention to still use literals `{}`, instead of constructors in Objects `new Object`, [See Google Javascript Guides](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Array_and_Object_literals#Array_and_Object_literals).

Answer (score 0):

### Almost Always, yes

I think saying things like "one should always prefer this" is a bit too generalized, there are always exceptions.  Object literals are almost *always* preferred, but what to do when you are trying to clone complex sets of objects?? Or trying to instantiate [**module**](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/)?

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```